# Install Ubuntu 13.04 from Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, 10.04

I Use Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 (Dual Boot).
Two days ago I Download Ubuntu 13.04 from Ubuntu's Website and try to install Inside windows using wubi.exe. But there is no choice for "Install Inside Windows", There is only one choice "Demo and Full Installation". So I decide to upgrade my older version 10.04 to 13.04.
Now problem is My pen drive not working so there is any other way to upgrade 10.04 to 13.04 from its ISO file, without pen drive or CD ROM ? I do not wish to upgrade from "Upgrade Manager"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Use follow Following Steps In Windows to Bring "Install Install Inside Windows" Button.

```
Mount Ubuntu 13.04 ISO Using demon tools. (In My Case, Virtual Drive is G:)
Then open G: in CMD

Now Use Following Code

`G:\>wubi.exe -force-wubi (This is For 32bit Machine)`

`G:\>wubi.exe --force-wubi (This is For 64bit Machine)`

`This Code Work for me, In you case It want, You can try alternate code from 32bit for 64bit and for 64bit use 32bit code. Its work 100%`
```

Comment: 64bit code work for me on 32bit (x86) Machine :)